# I am getting this error when I am trying to add files from the local drive to the Repository in the local drive

Tags: git, ant

I am getting this error when I am trying to add files from the local drive to the Repository in the local drive that is a clone of Git repository of same name:-

> run_git-add:
>
> [exec] fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):
>   .git       [exec] Result: 128      [echo] add done

Please guide me

This is my whole command in ANT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--New Build File-->

<project default="run_git-add">

<!--GIT COMMAND LOG-->
<macrodef name="git">
        <attribute name = "command" />
        <attribute name = "dir" default = "" />
        <element name = "args" optional = "true" />
        <sequential>
                <echo file="GIT_COMMAND_LOG" message="git @{command} &#xa;"
                    append="yes" />
                <exec executable = "git" dir = "@{dir}">
                    <arg value = "@{command}" />
                    <args/>
                </exec>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

<!--GIT INIT--> 
    <macrodef name = "git-init">
        <attribute name = "repository" />
        <sequential>
            <git command = "init">
                <args>
                    <arg value = "@{repository}" />
                </args>
            </git>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

<!--GIT ADD-->  
    <macrodef name = "git-add">
        <attribute name = "path" />
        <attribute name = "target1" />
        <sequential>
            <git command = "add" dir="@{path}">
                <args>
                    <arg value = "@{target1}" /> 
                </args>
            </git>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

<!--GIT COMMIT-->
    <macrodef name = "git-commit">
        <attribute name = "path" />
        <attribute name = "message" />
        <sequential>
            <git command="commit" dir="@{path}">
                <args>
                    <arg value= "@{message}" />
                </args>
            </git>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

<!--GIT PUSH--> 
    <macrodef name = "git-push">
        <attribute name = "path" />
        <attribute name = "branch" />
        <attribute name = "head" />
        <sequential>
            <git command = "push" dir="@{path}">
                <args>
                    <arg value = "@{branch}" />
                    <arg value = "@{head}" />
                </args>
            </git>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
<!--test fail-->
    <macrodef name="test">
        <attribute name = "path" default="hello" />
        <sequential>
            <fail message="fail">
                <condition>
                    <not>
                        <contains string="@{path}" substring="hello" />
                    </not>
                </condition>
            </fail>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

<target name="run_git-init">
<git-init repository="Hello-world"/>
<echo message="init done" />
</target>   

<target name="run_git-add">
<git-add path="C:\ANT MIGRATION\mig tool full\salesforce_ant_41.0\sample\retrieveUnpackaged1\classes" target1="C:\ANT MIGRATION\mig tool full\salesforce_ant_41.0\Hello-world"/>
<echo message="add done" />
</target> 
    </project>
```

Comment: I have used the run_git init command present in the starting to initialize the repository in my local drive but as I am trying to run the run_git add,  the same error pops up. I am not able to understand why is it not able to add the files in the local repository created by me

Comment: do not comment your question, but add more information is needed. It's better to comment the answers where relevant

Answer (score 0):

As per the message, it seems like you are not inside a git repository.

Try `git status` to verify that. 
Or check for a *hidden* **.git** directory inside your projects's root directory.
If you get the same error, it means that the directory is not git repository.

You should start by initializing the git repository to start using it as local git repo.

```
git init
```

And need to add the remote urls

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/github_repo_name/project_name.git
```

Answer (score 0):

That directory is not a *git working tree*.
To be able to use git you need to initialize a repository.

Assuming you started from scratch, you should run

```
git init
```

to create the repository and make that directory a *git working tree*.

Once initialized the repository you'll be able to add your files as you correctly did. You just missed the first step.

If you're supposed to collaborate with others it might be worth (or necessary) to setup a remote repository.

Assuming that you started from scratch you can do that with

```
git remote add origin URI
```

where URI can be either an HTTP address or an SSH resource.

I assumed that you started from scratch because cloning an existing repository doesn't require to run the `git init` command. Unless you unintentionally deleted the `.git` directory.

From your build it seems that you're trying to add a file that's outside the current directory. With git add you can only run files in the local tree.